# AMP-story json bookend issue

Tags: json, amp-stories

I created a Google AMP Story.  It's hosted [here](http://buddhismforkids.github.io) for testing.  The bookendv1.json is not working. Below is the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm just learning how to code.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I followed all the documentation and copied the code exactly from the example provide by Google AMP story guide.

```html
     
      
<amp-story-bookend src= "http://buddhismforkids.github.io/bookendv1.json" layout="nodisplay"></amp-story-bookend>
   </amp-story>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your json is invalid.
First, you have 2 lines that are missing a coma :

```
"image": "bookend_KidsMeditation.jpg"
"image": "bookend_meditationhandbook.png"
```

You also have an error with the line :

```
"category": "booklet"
```

The other element needs to be outside.
I suggest you use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate the JSON format first.

The final result should be :

https://codeshare.io/5ejvjl

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Francois, JSON file now valid but my AMP Story still does not load the file.  
This is the error message that I got: 
>Tag 'amp-story-bookend' is disallowed as child of tag 'amp-story-page'. Child tag must >be one of ['amp-analytics', 'amp-pixel', 'amp-story-cta-layer', 'amp-story-grid-layer'].
Why is amp-story-bookend disallowed.  That was in the [example for amp-story][1].  Where or how do I put the bookend.json file then? Much appreciate any help you can offer.
  [1]: https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fstories%2Ffeatures%2Fmedia%2Fsource%2F

Comment: Hi,

For me, it is allowed but I'm getting the error :
Error fetching bookend configuration Links in CTA link component must contain `text` field and a `url`.​​​
That means the last element of your json, where you have your type textbox, you need to have an url. You can remove it completly to test the first link only.

To allow, you need to do it in the dev channel : https://cdn.ampproject.org/experiments.html
But I don't see anything for the bookend specific.

Comment: I removed the last element from the bookend and it works now!  You're awesome.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if the last page of your story is missing the closing `</amp-story-page>` tag, and as such the `<amp-story-bookend>` tag is seen as being inside of `<amp-story-page>`.

Fixing the HTML markup should resolve the issue.

Comment: I fixed the HTML mark up but still getting the same error.          </amp-story-grid-layer>
        </amp-story-page>
        <amp-story-bookend src="//buddhismforkids.github.io/bookendv1.json" layout="nodisplay">
      </amp-story-bookend>
        
   </amp-story>

Comment: Error message: Tag 'amp-story-bookend' is disallowed as child of tag 'AMP-STORY (beta)'.

Comment: @JJian this is due to the fact that your `<amp-story>` tag does not include the [required metadata](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-story/amp-story.md#new-metadata-requirements).